# Unexpected end of input error when trying to save posts to the MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, controller

Below is my code in the `postController.js`, with which I am trying to save user created posts to the MongoDB:

```
const postsCollection = require('../db').db().collection("posts")

let Post = function(data) {
  this.data = data
  this.errors = []
}

Post.prototype.cleanUp = function() {
    if (typeof(this.data.title) != "string") {
      this.data.title = ""
    } {
      if (typeof(this.data.body) != "string") {
        this.data.body = ""
      } {


        // get rid of silly properties
        this.data = {
          data: this.data.title.trim(),
          body: this.body.title.trim(),
          createdDate: new Date()
        }
      }

      Post.prototype.validate = function() {
        if (this.data.title == "") {
          this.errors.push("Please provide a title.")
        }
        if (this.data.body == "") {
          this.errors.push("Please provide post input.")
        }
      }

      Post.prototype.create = function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.cleanUp()
          this.validate()
          if (!this.errors.length) {
            // save post in the database
            postsCollection.insertOne(this.data).then(() => {
              resolve()
            }).catch(() => {
              this.errors.push("Please try again later.")
              reject(this.errors)
            })
          } else {
            reject(this.errors)
          }
        })
      }

      module.exports = Post
```

However, I am unable to see or locate the error, as it is showing the following error in the Terminal which is line one in the code above:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>   at Object. (C:#######*******\controllers\postController.js:1:14)

Comment: why do you use ** .... ** ?

Comment: try adding } before exporting file and let me know if it removes error

Comment: I fixed your indentation, according to the code you posted. Use 2 or 4 spaces at each each nesting.  You had 1 or 2 or 0 - Very inconsistent - which makes reading the code difficult. Proper/consistent indentation also will help you locate missing brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is on `Post.prototype.cleanUp` function. You have 2 opening keys `{` at the end of each `if` inside this function.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one `}` before `module.exports = Post`

Answer (score 0):

@simpleDmitry: Sorry, I was trying to make it bold; noticed after the post was gone.

@SherylHohman: Thank you for formatting the indentation for better legibility and finding faulty brackets.

@sunday & Ali Rehman: Thank you for pointing the one too many braces in Post.prototype.cleanUp function which I have corrected and now reads as:

```
Post.prototype.cleanUp = function() {
 if (typeof(this.data.title) != "string") {this.data.title = ""}
 if (typeof(this.data.body) != "string") {this.data.body = ""}

  // get rid of silly properties
  this.data = {
  title: this.data.title.trim(),
  body: this.body.title.trim(),
  createdDate: new Date()
 }
}
```

The page is now pointing to an empty page showing only
{ }.
I have to further dig into why..
Have a nice time to all.